# ¿Qué causó el cambio en el significado de "rayuela"?

Tags: significado, definiciones, historia, acepciones, juegos

En las versiones del siglo XX del Diccionario de la lengua, *rayuela* tiene como una de sus acepciones (según el mapa de diccionarios):

> Juego *de muchachos* que consiste en sacar de varias divisiones trazadas en el suelo un tejo al que se da con un pie, llevando el otro en el aire y cuidando de no pisar las rayas y de que el tejo no se detenga en ellas.

Sin embargo, [en la última edición](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFJtK60) se han cambiado unas cuantas palabras que, si bien no modifican la idea principal de la palabra, no deja de ser curioso pues dice:

> Juego *infantil, tradicionalmente de niñas,* que consiste en ir desplazando un tejo, a puntapiés y a la pata coja, por varias casillas dibujadas en el suelo, procurando no pisar las rayas y que el tejo no quede detenido en ellas.

Más allá de un leve cambio en la forma de moverse, llama la atención cómo el juego toma un énfasis más de niñas, si bien no he notado lo mismo en mi cotidianidad (aunque no sean muchos los menores que jueguen rayuela). ¿Existe una mayor tradición del juego a nivel femenino? ¿Por qué solo en esta última edición se le da ese énfasis? (Ya en el diccionario de autoridades, se le asigna a la 'A' un toque *masculino* y a la E *femenino*)

Comment: Saliéndome del tema de la pregunta yo conocía ese juego como *trucumé*, no supe que también se llamaba *rayuela* hasta que leí el libro de Cortázar.

Comment: No entiendo el último comentario acerca del _Diccionario de autoridades_: "se le asigna a la 'A' un toque _masculino_ y a la E _femenino_".

Comment: Se debe referir a lo que dice el _Dicc. Aut._ en la entrada **A**, aunque no veo mucho la conexión: _En el orden es la primera, porque es la que la naturaleza enseña al hombre desde el punto del nacer para denotra el llanto, que es la priméra señál que dá de haver nacído; y aunque tambien la pronuncia la hembra, no es con la claridád que el varón, y su sonido (como lo acredita la experiencia) tira mas à la E, que à la A, en que paréce dán à entender, que entran en el mundo como lamentandose de sus priméros Padres Adán y Heva._

Comment: Capítulo 6 de [*A Century of Historical Change in the Game Preferences of American Children*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5406/jamerfolk.125.498.0411?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) puede ser de interés: [***Boys Who Play Hopscotch: The Historical Divide of a Gendered Space***](https://gse.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/users/derek-van-rheenen/Van%20Rheenen%2C%20boys%20who%20play%20hopscotch.pdf)

Comment: `"once a game played predominantly by boys, hopscotch has undergone a historical transformation in both the gender of play participants, as well as the cultural meanings attached to its gendered involvement. Thus, within the 20th century, the socially constructed space of the hopscotch diagram has come to be marked as feminine, a cultural text inhabited primarily by preadolescent girls. Boys who play hopscotch today run the risk of being deemed effeminate, a stigmatized marking in a patriarchal society"`

Comment: en méxico se le llama "avión" (por la forma del dibujo), el juego al que se le conoce por rayuela en méxico es muy diferente.

Comment: No creo que haya cambiado de sentido. La Rae pone: rayuela
1. f. Juego en el que, tirando monedas o tejos a una raya hecha en el suelo y a cierta distancia, gana quien la toca o más se acerca a ella.

2. f. Juego infantil, tradicionalmente de niñas, que consiste en ir desplazando un tejo, a puntapiés y a la pata coja, por varias casillas dibujadas en el suelo, procurando no pisar las rayas y que el tejo no quede detenido en ellas. Una raya, una rayuela. es un diminuitivo de raya. plaza, plazuela,

Comment: @Charlie, me refería a que los diccionarios de la RAE no han sido muy cercanos a lo políticamente correcto, desde sus inicios dan tintes varoniles o femeninos a las letras (cosa bastante rara) y sin embargo, el siglo pasado se inhibe al dejarlo como juego de muchachos. Si el juego es de tradición femenina, ¿a son de qué lo deja como juego de muchachos?

Comment: En la primera, seguramente no refiere a muchachos (masculino) sino muchachos (género no marcado) para referir a la edad joven de los que juegan a ella.  También, nota que sería la ASALE que escribe las acepciones, aunque el DLE lleva el nombre tanto de la RAE como ASALE (de que la RAE es miembro). La redacción con *muchachos* solo data del 1992.  Es posible que muchos mal interpretaron «de muchachos» como masculino (marcado), y por tanto adicionaron lo de «tradicionalmente de niñas» para recalcar que juegan ambos géneros, pero pues, tradicional más niñas que niños.

Comment: @guifa Pero para eso bastaba con sustituir *juego de muchachos* por *juego infantil*, como efectivamente han hecho. La apostilla me parece superflua.

Comment: Las definiciones de las palabras tienden a reflejar las costumbres y el uso comun de las palabras en la epoca en que el diccionario es publicado. Por eso es que vemos palabras nuevas, y algunas definiciones que cambian.

Comment: @Mike En Chile (sur) lo llamamos "luche", y los niños varones también jugábamos (hace veinte años)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo entiendo que el diccionario ha usado la palabra *muchachos* como genérica, tal y como especifica guifa en [su comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/qu%C3%A9-caus%C3%B3-el-cambio-en-el-significado-de-rayuela#comment46900_27323), simplemente por referirse así a la edad de las personas que suelen jugar a ese juego.

La primera vez que se registra la palabra es en el diccionario de Terreros y Pando de 1788, de la siguiente forma:

> RAYUELA, se llama tambien un juego que usan los muchachos tirando á una raya [...].

Se usa la voz *muchachos*, entiendo que en genérico. La RAE no recoge la palabra *rayuela* hasta 1803, de la siguiente forma:

> RAYUELA. Juego en el que tirando á una raya que se hace á distancia gana el que mas se acerca á ella, ó el que la toca.

Aquí por no especificar, no se especifica ni la edad ni el sexo del jugador. Esta acepción se mantiene así incluso hoy día. La acepción que incluye lo de "muchachos" es otra, que habla de un juego diferente, y data de 1970 en el DLE:

> Juego de muchachos que consiste en sacar de varias divisiones trazadas en el suelo un tejo al que se da con un pie, llevando el otro en el aire y cuidando de no pisar las rayas y de que el tejo no se detenga en ellas.

Debo decir que yo recuerdo ambos juegos de cuando era pequeño (década de 1980), y la sensación que tengo es que la primera acepción, la de tirar tejos a una línea, sí se refiere a un juego más orientado a niños (esta vez sí en masculino), y la segunda acepción, la de sacar tejos de una cuadrícula del suelo, sí era más de niñas. Aunque bien puede estar jugándome una mala pasada mi memoria. Los juegos que consistían en pintar cuadrículas y dar saltos sobre ellas (arrea, acabo de ver que [*infernáculo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LVp5h9o) es sinónimo de *rayuela*) los jugaban más las niñas, aunque esto con el tiempo pueda haber cambiado.

Supongo que la RAE debe referirse a eso con lo de "tradicionalmente de niñas". No sé si tal vez pueda ser un añadido desafortunado dada la tendencia actual hacia la igualdad de sexos, reflejada en que notas como esa están tendiendo a ser eliminadas del diccionario.